# lazy evaluation in infinte list

Tags: list, haskell, infinite

Hi I have the following code:

```
let f n (xs) = if n < 0 then f (n-1) (n:xs) else xs
f (-3) [] !! 1
```

and I expect it to print -4

But it does not print anything and keeps calculation in background.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting, but if you follow through how this will evaluate, the recursion only ends when `n >= 0`, yet you are subtracting 1 from it each time. Hence, infinite recursion. [You are building up an infinite list in `xs` as you do this, but the evaluation never stops for GHC to "see" this. So this is different from an "actual" infinite list like `[1..]` where you can quite happily do operations with some elements.]

Comment: Ordinary function application occurs immediately; the evaluation of the recursive call isn't delayed until some later time.

Answer (score 10):

Let's step through the evaluation:

```
f (-3) []
f (-4) [-3]
f (-5) [-4, -3]
f (-6) [-5, -4, -3]
f (-7) [-6, -5, -4, -3]
...
```

Considering this, what do you expect `f (-3) [] !! 1` to be? The value in the index `1` changes each iteration, so there's no way Haskell can know what it is until it reaches the non-recursive case at `n >= 0`, which never happens.

If you build the list in the other direction, it will work as you expect:

```
let f n = if n < 0 then n : f (n - 1) else []

> f (-3) !! 1
-4
```

Answer (score 2):

So here's a pretend integer type:

```
data Int2 = ... -- 2 bit signed integers [-2, -1, 0, 1]
  deriving (Num, Ord, Eq, ...)
```

Let's imagine that your function was defined on `Int2` values:

```
f :: Int2 -> [Int2] -> [Int2]
f n (xs) = if n < 0 then f (n-1) (n:xs) else xs
```

This makes it fairly easy to work out what one evaluation step looks like for `f n xs`:

```
f 1 xs = xs
f 0 xs = xs
f (-1) xs = f (-2) (-1 : xs)
f (-2) xs = f 1 (-2 : xs) -- because finite signed arithmetic wraps around
```

and from there we can work out the full value of `f n []`:

```
f 1 [] = []
f 0 [] = []
f (-1) [] = f (-2) [-1] = f 1 [-2, -1] = [-2, -1]
f (-2) [] = f 1 [-2] = [-2]
```

Each computed a value, but note how it took 3 evaluation steps before we got a list out of `f (-1) []`.

Now see if you can work out how many steps it would take to compute `f (-1) []` if it were defined on 4-bit numbers. 8-bit? 32-bit? 64-bit? What if it were using `Integer` which *has* no lower bound?

At no point does laziness help you because there's no partial result, only a recursive call.  That's the difference between:

```
lazyReplicate 0 _ = []
lazyReplicate n x = x : lazyReplicate (n - 1) x
```

and

```
strictReplicate n x = helper [] n x where
  helper xs 0 _ = xs
  helper xs n x = helper (x : xs) n x
```